# Find values in TXT file and replace with values from Excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a macro to find and replace values in a txt file.

The txt file is located in the route

> D:\Template\info.txt

This file looks like this (really the file has a HTML code, but I synthesized here the important part)

```
The current date and time is: %time%

GPU1 Temperature is: %GPU1T%
GPU1 Fan Speed is: %GPU1F%
GPU1 RPM are: %GPU1R%

GPU2 Temperature is: %GPU2T%
GPU2 Fan Speed is: %GPU2F%
GPU2 RPM are: %GPU2R%
```

and the Excel file looks like this
[image]

What I need is a macro that can find and replace the following:

```
Find %time% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell G2
Find %GPU1T% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell A2
Find %GPU1F% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell C2
Find %GPU1R% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell E2
Find %GPU2T% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell B2
Find %GPU2F% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell D2
Find %GPU2R% in the txt file and replace with the value of cell F2
```

After that, of course save the file but in a NEW location which is

> D:\GPUReport

but with the same name ***info.txt***

So far, trying to handle with this macro with no success

```
Sub FindAndReplaceText()

 Dim FileName As String
 Dim FolderPath As String
 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim I As Integer
 Dim SearchForWords As Variant
 Dim SubstituteWords As Variant
 Dim Text As String
 Dim TextFile As Object
 

   SearchForWords = Array("%time%", "%GPU1T%", "%GPU1F%", "%GPU1R%", "%GPU2T%", "%GPU2F%", "%GPU2R% ")
   SubstituteWords = Array(Range("G2"), Range("A2"), Range("C2"), Range("E2"), Range("B2"), Range("D2"), Range("F2"))
 

   FolderPath = "D:\Template\info.txt"
   
     Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
     FolderPath = IIf(Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\", FolderPath & "\", FolderPath)
     FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.txt")
   
     Do While FileName <> ""
       Filespec = FolderPath & FileName

         Set TextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(Filespec, 1, False)
           Text = TextFile.ReadAll
         TextFile.Close
         

         Set TextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(Filespec, 2, False)
           For I = 0 To UBound(SearchForWords)
             Replace Text, SearchForWords(I), SubstituteWords(I)
           Next I
         TextFile.Write Text
         TextFile.Close
       FileName = Dir()
     Loop
     
End Sub
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Expression `FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.txt")` will search files with `D:\Template\info.txt\\*.txt` mask. I think the FileName always will be empty. Perhaps FolderPath must be "D:\Template"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim txt As String, arr, c As Long
    
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("config").Range("A1:G2").Value
    txt = GetContent("C:\Tester\info.txt")
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        txt = Replace(txt, "%" & arr(1, c) & "%", arr(2, c))
    Next c
    PutContent "C:\Tester\info2.txt", txt
End Sub

Function GetContent(f As String) As String
    GetContent = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 1).readall()
End Function

Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 2, True).write content
End Sub
```

**Edit**: just noticed that your headers are different from your placeholder tokens but it would be easier to make them the same (but don't include the "%" around the headers).  Or add another row under the column headers to contain the placeholder text for that column.

Comment: New file info2.txt is created with an exact copy of info.txt but the values demarcated with the % sign aren't replaced, can you give me a hand please?

Comment: See my edit above - it will be much easier if you use the column headers as the placeholder text.

Comment: I changed the headers and I wrote the placeholder in the excel sheet. I mean, I changed GPU2 Temp for %GPU2T% (I did the same for the other headers) but the code doesn't replace the text in the new txt. Should I edit something special in the macro?

Comment: Don't include the `%` in the header names  - the macro adds those so you'll end up looking for (eg) `%%GPU2T%%`

Comment: Yes, that's the problem! I was including the % in the headers, I removed it and it's working. Thank you!